# How to convert the already written equation in google doc to latex equation format?

Tags: equations, conversion

I have written a document in google doc s. and all the equations are written normally. now I have to create the latex file out of that google doc only trouble I am having is the equations.

Comment: o found one tool GrindEq that will work on the ms word. but when I downloaded the file from google doc some equations have been changed a bit as overline became underline etc.. if anyone knows any solution to change the equation from google doc itself then it will be very helpful.

Comment: you could snip an image of the formula and use mathpix (most likely)

Comment: @davidCarlisle this works.. thank u so much..

Comment: @KJO I didn't actually try it, so I suggest the OP makes a self answer.